# Does every web page have a DOM and body element?

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a front-end application using Stencil.js.  We intend to nest our Stencil application on every page of our web application, which all use different technologies.  We have some pages that are Angular apps, others are made with React, etc.

Within the Stencil application, I want to modify the "body" element on the background web pages so that I can disable the scroll bar at various times.  I can easily make a call to "document.body", but I don't know if this is something that will always be available depending on the type of web page.  Does every web page contain a DOM, as well as a "body" element, regardless of what technology was used?

In case I need to clarify this, I'm talking about visual web pages loaded in web browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by "DOM" if not "Document Object Model" as in "the structure of the body of the document"? Arguably every non-empty page has a DOM.

Comment: A page is a document, and therefore has a DOM

Comment: A page can also exist inside an iframe which has a separate DOM from the containing page.

Comment: ["*The Document.body property represents the <body> or <frameset> node of the current document, or null if no such element exists.* - MDN Document.body"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is DOM? (summary and importance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976344/what-is-dom-summary-and-importance)

Comment: Asking if each web page has a DOM is like asking if roads still exist when you drive different cars. It makes no sense. It doesn't matter what framework or tool set you made your web page in, there is always a DOM.

Comment: Is there always a body element?  That's mostly what I'm asking

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking yes, but there are exceptions.

`document.body` is a getter and it looks up the body element every time you refer to it in code. If your code executes before `body` element created or even if there is one, you will get `null`. The common case where you might not have `document.body` ready yet is when you have a synchronous script tag in `head` element or if your application is a browser extension set up to execute before the page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think I'm now going to add a check to make sure "document.body" doesn't return null, in case there is a conflict during page load.  This leads me to ask, do all types of web pages (Angular, react, Java Web Application, etc) ultimately compile down to an HTML document with a body element?  I believe I will reference "document.body", but I want to safely let the customer know that the scrollbar behavior will be consistent across every page on the website (I also am not sure what technologies other teams are using, since there are many different web pages on the site)

Comment: I believe if the link to your javascript is located at the bottom of the body element then you do not have anything to worry about. all modern javascript frameworks(react/angular/svelte/vue) are just javascript and should be treated as just javascript. All they do is attempt to efficiently modify dom elements with minimum effort.