# what exactly is document object model?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a confusion regarding the document object model, I have read that the DOM is a tree like structure with nodes that represent the contents of a web page.so does this means the browser uses tree data structure for storing the DOM? if its a tree like structure then why does the browser's console shows it as an object? what really is a DOM? a tree data structure or an object?

I tried reading the MDN docs but couldn't really understand it

Comment: "*if its a tree like structure then why does the browser's console shows it as an object?*" tree data structures are still composed of objects... There is no reason to expect the two are in any way incompatible or even mutually exclusive.

Comment: @VLAZ so is it correct to say that the DOM is a tree data structure?

Comment: Yes. It mirrors the HTML tags. The HTML tags form a tree. Since the DOM comes from the HTML markup, then it's also going to be a tree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is DOM? (summary and importance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976344/what-is-dom-summary-and-importance)

Comment: @LaurenRutledge is the DOM a tree data structure which is made up of objects or the DOM is just a collection of related objects (related here means related in some hierarchial way) and the tree is just for logical understanding?

Comment: browsers use a tree data structure to store the DOM.

However, when you interact with the DOM through the browser's developer tools console, it often appears as an object because it is exposed to JavaScript as an object-oriented API. This means that you can use JavaScript to manipulate and interact with the DOM using methods and properties provided by this API. Is this explanation correct?

Answer (score 0):

> does this means the browser uses tree data structure for storing the DOM

Regardless of how the browser stores its information, the DOM is an object that exposes **to you** a tree data structure of objects.
This structure represents the items on the web page.

---

Just to record these worthy comments in an answer:

[As @VLAZ mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz): the HTML tags form a tree.

[@Lauren Rutledge replied](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7680801/lauren-rutledge): Does this answer your question? [What is DOM? (summary and importance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976344/what-is-dom-summary-and-importance)

I would strongly recommend anyone asking this question to read the answers to the SE question that Lauren references.